# Javascript Snippets in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

I'm sure this works in VS2010 but is there any way to get snippets to work in .JS files in Visual Studio 2008?

There's a [comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx#2892722) from way back in 2007 in ScottGu's post about JS Intellisense that it might have happened, but I would like to know if it has been officially taken off the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is.  If you look at more of Scott's blogs you will find this one.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/04/asp-net-html-javascript-snippet-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

He makes a comment of "Visual Studio has supported the concept of “snippets” for VB and C# in previous releases – but not for HTML, ASP.NET markup and JavaScript.  With VS 2010 we now support snippets for these content types as well."

Comment: too bad. I'm sure there are plenty of projects out there that cannot upgrade but could benefit from it.